# Javascript Dynamic object properties through functions returning strings

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I'm building a Backbone Marionette Application. In Marionette you can do something like:

```
Marionette.Application.extend({
    regions: {
        mainRegion: function(){return someCondition?"#A":"#B"},
        otherRegion: "#something"
    }
})
```

I'm trying to implement this in my application with custom objects. What is the best way to achieve this?
Currently, I'm checking for every value:

```
if(typeof obj == "function") {
    this.data.obj = obj();
}
else {
    this.data.obj = obj;
}
```

or the corresponding ?: expression. 
Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: What about that first snippet are you trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: you can duck type it: this.data.obj = obj.bind ? obj() : obj;

Comment: That I can dynamically pass either a string or a function returning a string for any property in my custom object.

Comment: call everything: String.prototype.call="".toString; x="abcdef"; x.call();

Comment: @dandavis I don't really get the first statement. Shouldn't it be like `String.prototype.call=function(){return this.toString();}` ?

Comment: @ManuelHoffmann: there's no need for the wrapper as "".toString turns "this" (whatever it may be) into a string. your wrapper does the same, but incurs the user-land function overhead for no benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underscore has a `result` method that does exactly what you want (see http://underscorejs.org/#result)

You can find the implementation here: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-128

Answer (score 0):

There is a potential solution (cue screaming) in adding value() [not to be confused with valueOf()] to every prototype you're interested in.

Function.prototype.value = function () { return this(); }; // Probably should be .call() so you can do arguments if necessary.

String.prototype.value = function () { return this; };

etc.

Then you can use this.data.obj = obj.value() for all calls.

If you're queasy about adding functions to prototypes, this isn't a solution you'd want to use.  Otherwise you could write a wrapper function that takes obj as an argument and returns the right thing based on the type.

The duck typing idea proposed by dandavis is also good IMHO.